# how to stop firing unrelated event of event bus

Tags: gwt

My problem is with how to stop firing unrelated event of event bus. as I got [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/We1Ot8ERKVQ) solution for Dialog box.
but it does not work in case of where one instance already initialize and try to create new instance of same class.

Just example: A below scroll panel has handler initialized. it used for document preview.

```
 class TestScroll extends ScrollPanel
      {
         public TestScroll(){

         }
         implemented onload()
          {
             // eventBus.addHandler code here.
           //here some preview related code
          }
             unload() method
            {
               //eventBus remove handler code
            }
      }
```

This preview has some data which contains some links that open different preview but with same class and different data structure,
Now  The problem is like  onUnload ( **which contains code of remove handler**) event does not load ,  because other panel opened. that does not mean previous panel unload.
So in that case, twice event handler registered. when one event fired then other event also fired.

Due to that, **Preview 1** data shows properly, but after that **Preview2** opened and when I close it, I find **Preview1=Preview2**.

so how can I handle such situation?

As per no of instance created each event fired. but I have to check some unique document id with if condition in event itself.
is there any other ways to stop unrelated event firing?

**Edit:**

```
public class Gwteventbus implements EntryPoint {

  int i=0;
  @Override
  public void onModuleLoad() {
   TestApp panel=new TestApp();

   Button button=new Button("Test Event");
   button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        TestApp panel=new TestApp();
        int j=i;
        new AppUtils().EVENT_BUS.fireEventFromSource(new AuthenticationEvent(),""+(j));
        i++;

   }
   });
   panel.add(button);
   RootPanel.get().add(panel);
   }        
}
public class AppUtils {
    public static EventBus EVENT_BUS = GWT.create(SimpleEventBus.class);
 }
 public class TestApp extends VerticalPanel{
  String testString="";
   public TestApp( ) {
    AppUtils.EVENT_BUS.addHandler(AuthenticationEvent.TYPE, new AuthenticationEventHandler()     {
     @Override
     public void onAuthenticationChanged(AuthenticationEvent authenticationEvent) {
        System.out.println("helloworld"+authenticationEvent.getSource());
    }
  });
   }

 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem, partly that is because you posted pseudo code. If you´re problem is due to some specific incorrect usage we're never are going to find out as we have to guess. If you want a usefull answer please provide some real code, of onload/onUnload, what events you regiter, how you fire events, and how you create the preview objects.

Comment: ok. I can not post original code due to enterprise app. I can put one test case sample. Just a case, `if any panel has a event bus handler registered, so you know that no of instance created than no of event bus initialized. and if any one event fire then all the event handler get called. so I want to fire only one event at a time related to that related panel only.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are wild guesses as it's difficult to really answer it without code and a clear description.

I'm guessing you have one eventbus for all the panels. So when you register a handler it is registered  with that one eventbus. In case you fire an event from one of the panels to the eventbus all panels will receive the event.

To fix this you can either create a new eventbus per panel or check who fired the event with `event.getSource()`.

If this doesn't make sense you probably are reusing a variable or use a static variable which actually should be a new instance or none static variable.

Comment: is there any ways to identify event of multiple instant for same class? 
just example edited questions, I created one sample test case of it. Refer `TestApp` has multiple instances created then on fire it will fire for all the events. 
is it possible to make event handler for instance specific?

Comment: As long as the panel fires to a global event bus everyone will get it. If the panel registers for a specific type of event it well get all events of that type when fired. By identifying who fired it   or set values in the event to identify a specific event you can check for it when an event is fired. A possible solution in your example is to pass i (or j) as a argument to the constructor of `TestApp`, or instead of the int variable you could pass `panel` as the source in the fire instead of the int value.  I'm not saying it is the best solution, but given the example it are possible solutions.

Comment: yes I used this varible `i` and `j` for testing purpose. thanks I was think this solution already...But the pass `panel` , that mean I have to set all the widgets values manually by taking it's instance because in java context we can assign class `this` with some other instance. like `this=panel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GwtEventService-Library](http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/) to fire specific events over a unique domain and every receiver that is registered at this domain receives that events then. You can handle as many different events/domains as you want.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a handler attached to the EventBus, you must first store a reference to the HandlerRegistration returned by the addHandler method:

```
HandlerRegistration hr = eventBus.addHandler(new ClickHandler(){...});
```

Then you can remove the handler with the removeHandler method:

```
hr.removeHandler();
```

A final note worth mentioning is that when using singleton views, like is typical with MVP and GWT Activities and Places, it is best practice to make use of a ResettableEventBus. The eventBus passed to an activity's start() is just such a bus. When the ActivityManager stops the activity, it automatically removes all handlers attached to the ResettableEventBus.

I would strongly recommend reading the GWT Project's documentation on:

- [Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html)
- [Large scale application development and MVP](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html)